# Flask restplus swagger "Model <List> not registered"

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-restplus

I keep getting  the following error whenever I try send a request.

```
<flask_restplus.fields.List object at 0x7f0a0878c790> not registered
```

The code can be found at -
https://github.com/Trace-Share/Trace-API/blob/9a30d5084b90bb1e9d58f21a8862113994e3d61d/traces_api/modules/unit/schemas.py#L43-L48

I found that removing `mac_mapping` and `ips` attribute lines removes the exception. Trying to add the `tcp_timestamp_min` attribute twice (under different name) causes the error to be risen again.

I have no idea what this exception means. It gets risen even when I try adding some bogus attributes that only lead to string. It always specifies List.

I am executing this by executing a unit test only for this specific function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize this error, so this might not be a useful answer, but Flask-Restplus is dead. Consider therefore changing [Flask-RESTX](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx) which is a maintained fork to eliminate the possibility that the error arise from there.